# How can I disable client side and proxy caching in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the proper (browser agnostic) way to disable page caching in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult NonCacheableData()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your MVC Action returns JSON instead of HTML such as in an ajax call you cannot use the meta-tag approach.