# Clear cache in mvc3.

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

[image]

I am using Sql server to upload images and the uploaded images are immediately reflected in the grid below.my problem is when ever i change or edit the picture,the picture is changed in the database but the grid shows the previous image that I had deleted.and i have to log out and lo-gin again to see the changes. Is there any way to over come this? Is there any way to clear cache each time the grid reloads?

Comment: Try to refresh the page. Is not the best practice but i think will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing your own attribute such as [no-cache] in the post below, and can use it on your controller to prevent caching.

[Prevent Caching in ASP.NET MVC for specific actions using an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011780/prevent-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-for-specific-actions-using-an-attribute)

http://dotnetnsqlcorner.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/disable-caching-for-controller-action.html?m=1

To disable client side caching,  you could also use [outputcacheattattribute] on your action result. Below post might help.

```
[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
```

[How can I disable client side and proxy caching in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860678/how-can-i-disable-client-side-and-proxy-caching-in-asp-net-mvc)

There are other ways of disabling the cache as well,, but I guess one of the above two approaches should do the job. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Duration for particular catche into your project:

just have a look to this:
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/programmatically-clearing-0

and If cache is formed on Client-side using Jquery-ajax then use::

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false
    //rest of your ajax setup
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target your action methods and create a no cache action filter attribute in addition to `cache: false` in your ajax call.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
     filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
     filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
     filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
     filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
     filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

     base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
  }
}
```

This is well explained [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011780/prevent-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-for-specific-actions-using-an-attribute). Hope it helps.